# Почему у Толстого не выделена кавычками прямая речь?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, кавычки, прямая-речь, бсп

> Глядя на знамя, ему все думалось: может быть, это то самое знамя, с которым мне придется идти впереди войск.

Это предложение ввело меня в ступор. Почему же прямая речь, идущая после двоеточия, не выделена кавычками?

Насколько мне известно, вот условия отсутствия кавычек при прямой речи ([Слова автора внутри прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158#pp158)):

> **1)** если нет точного указания, кому она принадлежит, или если приводится общеизвестная пословица, поговорка:
> *Про Ивашку Бровкина говорили: **крепкий*** (А. Т.); *Дома и хворать легче и жить дешевле; и недаром говорится: **дома и стены помогают*** (Ч.);
> **2)** если прямая речь приводится в таком виде, который может иметь и косвенная речь с тем же лексическим составом:
> *Но мне приходит в голову: **точно ли стоит рассказывать мою жизнь?*** (Т.);
> **3)** если в середину прямой речи вставлен глагол ***говорит***, играющий роль вводного слова, указывающего на источник сообщения:
> *Умру, **говорит**, и слава Богу, **говорит**; не желаю, **говорит**, жить* (Т.); *Я, **говорит**, самого вахмистра жандармерии из пистолета убить хочу* (Верш.);
> **4)** если в середину предложения, представляющего собой сообщение из периодической печати, вставлено указание на источник сообщения (такая вставка выделяется запятыми):
> *Речь оратора, **продолжает корреспондент**, вызвала горячую поддержку у большинства присутствующих.*
>
> То же, если высказывание говорящего передается приблизительно (тем самым утрачивается характер прямой речи): *Предлагаемый проект, **указал докладчик**, получил уже апробацию на практике.*

Разумеется, сразу, как начал думать над этим предложением, пришёл в голову второй пункт правила. Действительно, это предложение могло бы удовлетворить условие, изложенное во втором пункте правила, но вот незадача: в прямой речи присутствует личное местоимение *мне*, благодаря которому прямая речь теряет такой вид, который могла бы иметь и косвенная речь.

Что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Налево внизу, в тумане, слышалась перестрелка между невидными войсками. Там, казалось князю Андрею, сосредоточится сражение, там встретится препятствие, и «туда-то я буду послан, — думал он, — с бригадой или дивизией, и там-то со знаменем в руке я пойду вперед и сломлю все, что будет предо мной». Князь Андрей не мог равнодушно смотреть на знамена проходивших батальонов. **Глядя на знамя, ему все думалось: может быть, это то самое знамя, с которым мне придется идти впереди войск.***

1. Меня тоже заинтересовало это предложение
2. Здесь сохранен авторский текст (в частности деепричастный оборот оформлен не по современным правилам), но и во времена Толстого кавычки в таких предложениях ставили, например: *Часто **ему думалось**: «какъ бы хорошо было, если бы я не былъ женатъ…* [Н. А. Лейкин. Биржевые артельщики (1864)]

Здесь есть сочетание  **«ему думалось»,**  но **КАВЫЧКИ ПОСТАВЛЕНЫ**.
Соответственно, нельзя исключать **некорректное** оформление текста у Толстого даже по тем временам.  Возможно, тогда не было очень строгих и однозначных правил, но надо хотя бы доказать, что такой вариант применялся в текстах других авторов.

Я думаю, что предложение (без исправления деепричастного оборота) следует записать так: *Глядя на знамя, ему все думалось: **"может быть, это то самое знамя, с которым мне придется идти впереди войск".***

**Лирическое отступление от темы**

Гениальные писатели, как и все люди, могут ошибаться! Мы ценим их наследие, но стоит ли нам замирать в восхищении и перед их ошибками тоже?

**Примечание.** Если во многих прижизненных изданиях в обсуждаемой цитате **были кавычки,** то к Л.Н.Толстому **у меня больше нет вопросов,**  но появляются вопросы к тем, кто там **небрежно относится к нашим классикам**, в том числе к современным издателям, которые не замечают ошибок своих предшественников **и готовы ОБЪЯСНИТЬ все и вся.**

**3. Это предложение НЕЛЬЗЯ отнести к несобственно-прямой речи.**

Этот художественный прием использовался еще Пушкиным. В этом случае автор в мыслях и чувствах как бы отождествляет  себя с героем, но **грамматика текста строится обычным образом**, то есть текст не делится на слова автора и прямую речь.  Очень важно то, что **все местоимения и формы лица глагола** оформлены  с точки зрения автора, как и в косвенной речи (**ОН, ЕМУ**), там не может быть местоимения 1-го лица (**МНЕ**).

При использовании **несобственно-прямой речи** этот текст мог бы выглядеть так:

*Там,  внизу, в тумане, уже стреляют. Там сосредоточится сражение, там встретится препятствие, и туда он  будет послан, с бригадой или дивизией, и там  со знаменем в руке пойдет вперед и сломит все, что будет передним.   А здесь пока  проходят батальоны,  несут знамена.  И  вот это знамя, может быть,  оно то самое знамя, с которым ему придется идти впереди войск.*

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Несобственно-прямая_речь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C)

Несо́бственно-пряма́я речь — это «отрывок повествовательного текста, передающий слова, мысли, чувства, восприятия или только смысловую позицию одного из изображаемых персонажей, причём передача текста повествователя **не маркируется ни графическими знаками (или их эквивалентами), ни вводящими словами (или их эквивалентами)»**[1].

**Несобственно-прямая речь на синтаксическом (и пунктуационном) уровне не выделяется из авторской**, но сохраняет лексические, стилистические и грамматические элементы, присущие речи говорящего, таким образом, располагаясь в промежуточном пространстве между полюсами прямой и косвенной речи.

Answer (score 6):

> Глядя на знамя, ему все думалось: может быть, это то самое знамя, с
> которым мне придется идти впереди войск.

Скорее всего, это **несобственно-прямая речь**: автор передаёт думы героя. Если бы была прямая речь, то её вводили бы слова "он думал", а не "ему думалось".

> Несобственно-прямая речь — это непрямой способ передачи чужого
> высказывания, близкий к самому этому высказыванию, позволяющий
> тонко, как бы изнутри характеризовать героя, проникать в его
> внутренний мир, косвенно оценивать его поступки, поведение, речевую
> манеру героя и т.д. В несобственно-прямой речи чужое высказывание,
> сохраняя некоторые свои существенные черты, но без ярких примет личной
> принадлежности, воспроизводится в формах авторской речи. Речь
> персонажа как бы облекается авторской речью и воспроизводится в формах
> последней. Используя несобственно-прямую речь, автор как бы
> перевоплощается в героя, оставаясь в то же время в рамках своей
> авторской речи. Поэтому очень часто несобственно-прямая речь
> естественно и незаметно переходит в прямую речь персонажа.
> **Несобственно-прямая речь позволяет автору как бы говорить и думать за
> своих персонажей**. Тем самым создается взаимосвязь между образом
> автора и образами персонажей, достигается единство художественного
> текста.
>
> Лыжин проснулся и сел в постели. Какой смутный, нехороший сон!
> И почему агент и сотский приснились вместе? Что за вздор! (А П.
> Чехов).
>
> Ивану Ильичу нужно было явиться в штаб армии, рапортовать о
> прибытии парохода с огнеприпасами и передать накладную. Но черт его
> знает, где искать этот штаб (А.Н. Толстой).

https://studfile.net/preview/1101520/page:21/

В художественной литературе часто несобственно-прямая речь **употребляется в виде второй части бессоюзного сложного предложения** и отражает реакцию действующего лица на воспринимаемое им явление. У нас тоже бессоюзное предложение, вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой.

Answer (score 2):

Сложный и интересный вопрос. Я не смогу дать полный ответ, но попытаюсь обозначить ключевые слова и предложить направления для дальнейшего поиска.

Обозначение прямой речи — один из сложных и недостаточно проработанных вопросов во многих языках. Он до сих пор активно изучается. Приём, который использовал Л.Н. Толстой в этом отрывке, называют "необозначенная прямая речь" (термин ввёл чешский теоретик литературы Л. Долежел в 1960 г.).

В книге "Типы повествования в русской литературе XIX-ХХ вв." известный лингвист Н. А. Кожевникова как раз приводит обсуждаемый отрывок из Л.Н. Толстого в качестве примера необозначенной прямой речи, которая "вводится при помощи глагола речи или мысли".

Чуть больше о необозначенной прямой речи с конкретными примерами отличия от несобственно-прямой речи можно найти [здесь](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/priemy-subektivatsii-v-sovremennoy-proze-yavleniya-modifikatsii).

Отдельно замечу, что во многих прижизненных изданиях в обсуждаемой цитате были кавычки. [Например](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=24sUAAAAYAAJ&q=%22%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%22&dq=%22%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZrcvws-rqAhXwsosKHS-GAqYQ6AEwBnoECAYQAg).

Answer (score 1):

Во вором ответе я хочу раскрыть подробнее тему, связанную с несобственно-прямой речью.

**О несобственно-прямой речи**

По материалам источника https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/nesobstvenno-pryamaya-rech-71732.html

**1.  История термина**

Впервые о несобственно-прямой речи заговорил лингвист П. Козловский **в 1890 г.** (работа «О сочетании предложений прямой и косвенной речи»). Он описывал случаи превращения «чужой речи» в речь самого автора, назвал такие конструкции «эпическим приемом». Позднее Т.Тоблер употребил термин **«своеобразное смешение косвенной и прямой речи».**

В разные периоды несобственно-прямая речь **понималась как**: эпический прием (В.Козловский); стилистический прием (И.И.Ковтунова, И. А.Поспелов); синтаксическая структура  (В.В.Бабайцева, и др.).

В литературе встречались **термины**: смешение прямой и косвенной речи (Т.Тоблер), свободная косвенная речь (Ш.Балли), завуалированная или скрытая речь (Т.Калепки), несобственно-авторская речь (Б.М.Соколов), фигуральная речь (В. Козловский), получужая речь (В.Н.Волошинов), несобственно-прямая речь (большинство).

Так или иначе, но в конце концов **общеупотребительный термин** был определен и обозначен.  Например, в 70-х годах XX века он уже широко применяется **в учебной литературе**, в частности в книге  Валгиной для вузов «Современный русский язык, Синтаксис». В  школьных учебниках эта тема также разбирается, например: Русский язык 9 – 11 классы, 2007 год.

**2. Средства выражения несобственно-прямой речи**

Не надо думать, что несобственно-прямая речь не имеет никаких  видимых средств выражения, их даже очень много.

Все средства выражения несобственно-прямой речи можно разделить **на три группы**: средства узнавания и выделения ее из авторского контекста; средства связи несобственно-прямой речи с авторскими словами; средства, которые одновременно и связывают и выделяют несобственно-прямую речь из контекста.

**Средства узнавания и выделения** несобственно-прямой речи:

а) лексические: эмоционально-экспрессивно окрашенные слова и словосочетания, выражающие определенное отношение

б) морфологические: смена временных форм, смена модального плана

в) синтаксические: ввод восклицательных, вопросительных предложений, номинативных, вводных конструкций, интонация

г) графические: шрифтовое выделение элементов несобственно-прямой речи

д) стилистические: повторы.

**Средства связи** несобственно-прямой речи с авторским контекстом:

а) морфологические: местоимения, в частности, анафорические, союзы. Например: Пошла — и что ж? медведь за ней!

б) синтаксические:  контекстуально-неполные предложения.

**Средства связывающие и выделяющие**.

Это слова ввода несобственно-прямой речи в контекст (глаголы со значением мысли, речи).

**3. О формальном признаке несобственно-прямой речи**

Но практически во всех источниках указывается формальный признак несобственно-прямой речи. Это отсутствие местоимений и личных форм глагола **1-го лица** (я, мне) при передаче **речи персонажей**,  которые используются в прямой речи. В несобственно-прямой речи применяются формы **3-го лица**  (он, она, они).

Answer (score 1):

**О термине "необозначенная прямая речь"**

Я решила выделить  эту тему в отдельный ответ, чтобы не смешивать  ее с несобственнно-прямой речью.

Перечитала еще раз, и очень внимательно, отрывок Толстого и пришла к выводу, что это разные вещи.

*Налево внизу, в тумане, слышалась перестрелка между невидными войсками. Там, казалось князю Андрею, сосредоточится сражение, там встретится препятствие, и «туда-то я буду послан, — думал он, — с бригадой или дивизией, и там-то со знаменем в руке я пойду вперед и сломлю все, что будет предо мной». Князь Андрей не мог равнодушно смотреть на знамена проходивших батальонов. Глядя на знамя, ему все думалось: "может быть, это то самое знамя, с которым мне придется идти впереди войск".*

Примечание. В приведенном варианте текста кавычки поставлены.

Толстой посвящает этот отрывок мыслям героя,  как бы погружается в них. Но это не метод несобственно-прямой речи, хотя тоже особый прием, имеющий свое название.

Мысли пересказаны как бы дословно, как и в прямой речи. Но **слова автора** всё-таки присутствуют в тексте в виде **вводного предложения** (казалось князю Андрею), потом Толстой переходит к прямой речи, заключенной **в кавычки**, но так, что она кажется встроенной в текст.

Потом следует чисто авторский текст (*князь Андрей не мог равнодушно смотреть на знамена проходивших батальонов*),  а заканчивается отрывок предложением со словами автора и выделенной прямой речью, которую как раз и **лишили кавычек**.

И немного о самом термине. **Необозначенная прямая речь?** Вероятно, имеется в виду **дословный** пересказ мыслей, а также **слова автора**, отодвинутые на второй план, по возможности скрытые. В несобственно-прямой речи от них отказались совсем.

Впечатление от текста после приведенного анализа не улучшилось, а скорее, ухудшилось. **Не такой чистоты приема**, как у Пушкина, получилось **смешение** оформительских стилей.